# Find the largest positive delta in an ordered list of positive integers

Tags: python, algorithm, delta

I am writing a python script to look at a table of rankings, where a team's performance over several seasons is ranked compared to various others, running from most recent back in time, like

```
        Latest ->                                      <- Earliest
Team A: 10  10  12  12  13  13  13  14  15  14  16  13  11  15  14      
Team B: 14  14  15  16  15  7   14  14  15  10  22  15  15  11  16
```

What I want is the largest positive improvement, over any time span, for every team. What I don't want is the absolute value of lowest to highest point, so for a team that goes

```
Team C: 30 18 20
```

the largest rise is only 2, even though the largest delta is 12.

In the case of A, above, the largest rise is from #16 (7 seasons ago) to #10 this season, whereas for B, the largest rise is from #22 to #7, between 11 and 6 seasons ago.

I want to loop over a list like this, and return something like

```
Team A:  6
Team B: 15
```

I could pop() each season, and subtract it from all previous seasons, then save the largest positive int, but that feels sloppy. OTOH, sorting the list and pulling the first and last elements would make declines in rank show up as well. (I only want to measure gains, not losses.)

Is there a simple way to take in the array of season performances find the largest delta between recent, good team performance and earlier, worse performance, without that looping?

Comment: Is it max(A) - min(A) is that you want largest difference?

Comment: *The* Clay Shirky? Sorry, couldn't resist -- profile looks like yes, that one.

Comment: I don't want the largest absolute value, I want the largest positive value. (Teams tend to have a hard time rising in the rankings, but an easy time falling.) So I am interested in a team that goes from #22 to #7, but _not_ a team that goes from #7 to #22.

Comment: Is this not the largest consecutive subsequence problem?

Comment: Also, @tripleee, yes, that's me. There aren't _two_ people with this name :)

Comment: @cricket_007, could be. Didn't know the phrase 'largest consecutive subsequence problem' til now. Will look it up, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the list, keep track of min value and the current largest rise (which is the `current list member - min`). Every time you process a list member, check if it is the new min and update current largest rise as needed.

You don't need to subtract from all previous seasons, you just need to check if the new element is the new minimum and if it makes the largest rise yet.

Ex.

```
def find_max_pos_delta(my_scores):
    my_list = map(int, my_scores.strip().split())
    my_min = current_largest = None
    for rank in my_list:
        if my_min is None or rank < my_min:
            my_min = rank
        new_largest = rank - my_min
        if current_largest is None or new_largest > current_largest:
            current_largest = new_largest

    return current_largest

assert find_max_pos_delta('30 18 20') == 2
assert find_max_pos_delta('10  10  12  12  13  13  13  14  15  14  16  13  11  15  14  ') == 6
assert find_max_pos_delta('14  14  15  16  15  7   14  14  15  10  22  15  15  11  16') == 15
```

The time complexity O(n) as it loops over all the elements.

Note that I chose to reverse the goal and the list but the result is the same. ie. I'm going from current year to past but also from higher rank to lower one.

Comment: Nice, many thanks, and of course this is it -- I missed the fact that as I go through the list, I can skip an increasing number of elements as the current max range grows. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not very pretty, but I believe you can identify the largest improving sequence with:

```
def find_greatest_rise(rank_list):
    rank_list = rank_list[::-1] #reverse the rank list so we iterate moving forward in time
    i = 0
    if len(rank_list) > i + 1:
        bottom = 0
        top = 0
        delta = 0
        end_of_list = False

        while not end_of_list:
            curr_rank = rank_list[i]
            for j, r in enumerate(rank_list[i + 1:]):
                if curr_rank - r > 0:
                    if curr_rank - r >= delta:
                        delta = curr_rank - r
                        bottom = curr_rank
                        top = r
                else:
                    i += j + 1
                    break

                if j == len(rank_list[i + 1:]) - 1:
                    end_of_list = True

        print "bottom: {}, top: {}, delta: {}".format(bottom, top, delta)
```